# How to get the name of the previous in pipe cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

How to get the name of the previous in pipe cmdlet? For example:

```
gci myDir\*.ps1 | % { $prevCmdletName = ...?... }
resolve-Path myDir\*.ps1 | % { $prevCmdletName = ...?... }
gci myDir\*.ps1 | ? { $_.fullname -match 'tests' } | % { $prevCmdletName = ...?... }
test1.ps1, test2.ps1 | % { $prevCmdletName = ...?... }
```

Is there a common code to determinate the previous in pipe cmdlet? Is there a module with such functions?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a possible [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  What problem/scenario do you have that you think this will help with?

Comment: `How to get the name of the previous in pipe cmdlet?` 
How to get the name of previous WHAT in pipe cmdlet?

Comment: "scenario" - logging. And I'm interested to expand my knowledge.
"What" - an ideal case is a command object with argument values.  a suitable case is name of cmdlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you may be after is a transcript `start-transcript filepath\filename`. It really depends on what the desired end result will be, but a transcript will indicate to you what commands are executing and what those commands are doing.

If you want your code to tell you what command you are running while you're running it, then that's a seemingly strange requirement - however, can be done.

```
gci c:\ | % {(Get-PSCallStack).Position.StartScriptPosition.GetFullScript()}
```

Doing this will obscure your output, but you can add it as one of the outputs. Getting creative with how you then use it to determine the precise previous argument in a pipeline, could be done by taking that string output and splitting it by the pipeline character. Whichever output you desire, you will need to encapsulate that in a script block via calculating which item in that split list you're after. Doing this all in one line as part of the pipe will yield undesired results.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you are after.

The previously iterated `$PsItem/$_` in a ForEach?

Other than storing the previous in a variable?

```
$prevCmdletName = ""
Get-ChildItem myDir\*.ps1 | ForEach-Object { 
    "Current {0} previous {1}" -f $_,$prevCmdletName 
    $prevCmdletName=$_
}
```

Comment: No, not value. Previous-in-pipe Cmdlet name.  )

Comment: You mean you want to determine the originator of a pipe from the receiving side?

Comment: originator of a pipe... pipe can consist of several cmdlet. for example: `gci | get-content | run-MyCmdLet`. `gci` is originator, isn't it? `get-content` is previous-in-pipe (I don't know good termin for it). Object creator (for `run-MyCmdLet`) is `get-content`. I would like to get info about `get-content` )

Comment: No. I consider a pipe two ended. Your example describes two seperate pipes. I don't know if there is way to obtain the orginator which could also be a normal .exe not just a cmdlet.

Comment: I'm agree - Let's name it `originator` )  And I'm agree there are cases for which it is difficult to give a single answer - .exe, array, filters. It's the reason of my question. I want to understand.

Comment: There is a Get-PSCallStack gets a traditional caller by stack. It's familiar. `Originator` is not caller. What a way to work with `Originator`? What is it true name? I feel like I don't know anything important.